# Kotlin corountines : Note: end time exceeds epoch:

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Combine `runBlocking` and `withContext` seems to dispatch the message 
`Note: end time exceeds epoch:`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        runBlocking {
            withContext(DefaultDispatcher) {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use many coroutines like this and the logcat is spammed, any idea to avoid this ? Another way to do this, for example :

```
var projects: List<ProjectEntity>? = runBlocking {
    withContext(DefaultDispatcher) {
        //Get the ProjectEntity list
    }
}
projects?.let {
    onResult(projects)
}
```

**EDIT**

I try something based on your comments (thank you), but I can't get a similar result as my example above :

```
Log.d("Coroutines", "getMostRecent start")
var localeProject: ProjectEntity? = null
launch {
    withContext(CommonPool) {
        Log.d("Coroutines", "getRecentLocaleProject")
        localeProject = getRecentLocaleProject()
    }
}
Log.d("Coroutines", "check localeProject")
if (localeProject != null) {
    //Show UI
}
```

In Logcat :

```
D/Coroutines: getMostRecent start
D/Coroutines: check localeProject
D/Coroutines: getRecentLocaleProject
```

I want to separate async and sync stuff, there is no way like this ? I really want to avoid all the callbacks things in my repositories when possible.

Comment: Do not use `runBlocking` in Android UI callbacks. It blocks the UI thread.

Comment: you can't assign the result of an async computation directly, so your `projects` example doesn't work like that. You can do it for example like https://gist.github.com/zapl/29c686fbd6ae02060f5f758e144260bf (Note: I'd IRL use `ScopedAppActivity()` and just `launch` rather than `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)`)

Comment: my example works fine, but it's thread blocking, as @MarkoTopolnik says ( it wasn't clear, thank you) and my logcat is spammed with that mysterious message

Comment: In the end, thank to all comments, I change all my stack : database layer is full sync but with suspend functions and my presenter layer handle async logic. The mysterious message `Note: end time exceeds epoch:` disappears but stays mysterious...

Answer (score 2):

Markos comment is right, you should not block the UI thread.

You should use `launch` or `async` and use `withContext` to switch back to the UI thread.

You find some examples here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#structured-concurrency-lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy

```
class MainActivity : ScopedAppActivity() {

    fun asyncShowData() = launch { // Is invoked in UI context with Activity's job as a parent
       // actual implementation
    }

    suspend fun showIOData() {
        val deferred = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // impl      
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
          val data = deferred.await()
          // Show data in UI
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware, that the example uses the new coroutine API (>0.26.0), that renamed the Dispatchers. So `Dispatchers.Main` corresponds to `UI` in older versions.

Comment: what is `ScopedAppActivity` here?

Comment: This is too complex, you just need `val ioResult = withContext(IO) { blockingCall() }`. No need for `async`.

Comment: @TimCastelijns It's from [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#structured-concurrency-lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy).

Comment: I want to confine my coroutines in my repository layer and avoid callbacks on basic calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
var localeProject: ProjectEntity? = null
launch {
    withContext(CommonPool) {
        localeProject = getRecentLocaleProject()
    }
}
if (localeProject != null) {
    //Show UI
}
```

> I want to separate async and sync stuff, there is no way like this ?

When you `launch` a coroutine, semantically it's like you `start`ed a thread. Intuition tells you that you can't expect `localeProject != null` just after you've started the thread that sets it, and this is true for the coroutine as well. It's even stronger: you are *guaranteed* not to ever see `localeProject != null` because `launch` only adds a new event to the event loop. Until your current method completes, that event won't be handled.

So you can forget about top-level `val`s initialized from async code. Not even `lateinit var`s can work because you have no guarantee you'll see it already initialized. You must work with the loosest kind: nullable `var`s.